# Pandas apply(): how to multiply selected columns based on string match and return complete dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I have columns like names,FDR%,age,FCR%,income.I want to select the columns with '%' string match and multiply by 100.Finally, i would like to return the entire dataframe with the '% column values changes. I tried as under:

```
df_final=df_1.filter(like='%', axis=1).apply(lambda x:x*100)
df_final
```

This just returns the subset i.e. columns operated upon  FDR% and FCR%.I need the entire dataframe returned with the corresponding changes.

Also is there a better method of achieving the same?

Comment: looks like you only need to drop `axis=1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select columns from DataFrame returned by `filter` and multiple by `100`:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'FDR%':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'FCR%':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
})

cols = df_1.filter(like='%').columns
df_1[cols] *= 100
print (df_1)
   A  FDR%  C  FCR%  E
0  a   400  7   100  5
1  b   500  8   300  3
2  c   400  9   500  6
3  d   500  4   700  9
4  e   500  2   100  2
5  f   400  3     0  4
```

Or use mask by [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) or [`Series.str.endswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.endswith.html) and select columns with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
mask = df_1.columns.str.contains('%')
#alternative
#mask = df_1.columns.str.endswith('%')
df_1.loc[:, mask] *= 100
```

**Notice**:

`apply` here for multiple is bad choice, because loops under the hood, so slow. Fast solution is multiple by scalar only.